# Можно ли быть "квитыми"?

Tags: значение-слов, лексика

Значение слова "квиты" можно определить по квитанциям, с которыми мы обычно имеем дело. А насколько употребительно выражение "мы квиты", а также однокоренные слова (поквитаться, расквитаться)? Мне кажется, что они устаревают. В ГРАМОТЕ.РУ дается  только неизменяемая форма без названия  "квиты" - получается, что нельзя, например, сказать "расстаться квитыми"?

Comment: Сейчас попалось на глаза английское выражение we are quits. Перевод: мы квиты. Английское quits здесь предиктивное прилагательное, согласно Оксфордскому словарю. Мне кажется, русское квиты - это тоже прилагательное

Comment: в русском языке часть речи определяется независимо от английского языка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Расстаться квитыми" нельзя, потому что квиты (квит)-галлицизм,разговорный предикатив (наречие в значении сказуемого)= ничего не должен, в расчёте.

Когда-то слово употреблялось в 4 значениях:

КВИТ quitte adj.,> нем. quitt. 1. устар. Квитанция, расписка. БАС-1. У него взял пристав Федор Нагой кабалу квит на пять рублев, что был винен Иван Зубатой. Польск. д. 3 759. 1570.  Да с двора по возу сена, и в том де им даваны квиты и чтоб то впредь в платеж зачесть. Докл. в Сенате V (2) 646. 1715. // Сл. 17.

1. Расчет по денежным долгам. Пускай решают сами, И ежели хотят, не отлагая вдаль, Подпишем записи - и квит они с долгами. 1818. Шаховской Путодомы. // Ш. 483. ||Уничтожение долга в карточной игре. Ян. 1804. ♦ Играть на квит. Играть на весь свой выигрыш. БАС-1. - Вот и стали играть на квит да квит; я на него рублей восемьдесят и набил. Толст. Зап. маркера.
2. перен. Расчет. Я по смерть только обещало вас любить. Теперь квит изо всего: подите от меня прочь. Эмин Ведомости из ада. // Сатир. проза 18 в. 102. Я в том себя сравняю Такие ж у себя я руки нахожу. (дает пощечину Высоносу). Мы квит.1793. Княжнин Чудаки 483.
3. простореч., в знач. сказ. Кончено, конец. БАС-1. Надеюсь, что ты все это прочитаешь хладнокровно, пожмешь плечами, положишь в ящик, замкнешь, и делу квит. 1.11. 1809. Батюшков - Н. И. Гнедичу. - А что ж он <хозяин сапожной мастерской> нашу кровь сосал. да и квит. Толст. Война и мир. - Народу то сколько поедает шахта эта. Вот Степана тоже. Молодой, сердешный, а вижу - квит ему, не подымется. А. Дерман Странный вопрос. // РБ 1900 8 1 151.

От слова КВИТ образовался уже в русском языке глагол квитаться - расквитаться, поквитаться,квитающийся,квитавшийся,квитаясь,квитавшись (по Зализняку)= рассчитаться с долгами

Квит в эту парадигму никак не вписывается, это неизменяемый предикатив.

Comment: "Квиты" точно предикативное наречие? По форме похоже на краткое прилагательное. А полное прилагательное "квитый" не употреблялось никогда?
  И еще интересна дальнейшая судьба слова. Мне кажется, оно устаревает. Мы обычно говорим "в расчете", а глагол "расквитаться" приобрел, скорее, переносный смысл.

Comment: Предикативы, конечно, близки к кратким прилагательным, но вопрос к нему всё-таки как?(в расчёте, квит), а не каков?, хотя по форме - да, похоже, потому и ассоциации такие, но ведь это заимствование, формы просто совпали. А дальнейшая судьба - пока в разговорной речи употребляется довольно часто, но только в значении "в расчёте", а в значении сущ."расчёт"и в знач."кончено" уже устарело.

Comment: Используется только форма "мы квиты", вот я и думаю, что это краткое прилагательное в форме мн. числа. Понаблюдаю за этим словом в речи - возможно, оно всё-таки встречается.